# looking for an API that send a text message without inputing carrier

Tags: php

I am trying to find an API that the code is already done where you can send a text message to a phone without them inputting a carrier. The number knows the carrier based on the sequence of numbers. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing of SMSes is done on the HLR and the number sequence does not really matter, since you can keep you number and change provider, in most countries anyway. You'll need to go through a provider, like Clickatell in South Africa. The SMS providers will have their own APIs

Comment: any recommendation about the provider?

Comment: What country are you in?